# Custom collection view cell not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Trying to create a custom cell but when I am adding label in the cell `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` doesn't work.

Without label cell UI:

[image]

and the iPad simulator UI is:

[image]

But when I am adding label into the cell:

[image]

The iPad Simulator UI becomes :

[image]

In `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` in the method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let emptySpace = 87*2 + 10
    let remainingWidth = Int(self.view.frame.width) - emptySpace
    return CGSize(width: remainingWidth/2, height: remainingWidth/2)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you building with Xcode 11 (GM 2)? I had similar issues implementing `sizeForItemAt`.

It seems something is causing the collection views to disregard the size returned in `sizeForItemAt` and instead use the size of the child views.

What worked for me is setting `Estimate Size` to `None` on the collection view in Interface Builder.

This is not ideal, especially if you have many cells, but it was the only fix I found unfortunately.

[image: setting <code>Estimated Size</code> to <code>None</code> on the collection view in Interface Builder]